# Excel - Macro Changing sheets and Fill to End - Compile Error

Tags: excel, compiler-errors, autofill, vba

I am creating a Macro to run consecutively on about 25 sheets, where I am naming a cells in a specific column.  I have the code for filling to end, and for changing sheets.  But when I combine the codes, I am getting a warning:

> Compile Error:  Duplicate declaration in current scope

When I remove the DIM definition, it will run on the consecutive sheets, but only to the end of the first sheet.  My goal is to have each sheet dynamically filled to end in column N with a set name for each.

Here is the code I was working on

```
    Sub Mailbox_Name()
'
' Mailbox_Name Macro
' Adds Mailbox Name to Each Sheet

'
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
    Range("N1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Mailbox"
    Range("N2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ACC"
    Range("N2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N" & LR)
    Range("N2:N" & LR).Select

    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("ACPR").Select
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
    Range("N1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Mailbox"
    Range("N2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ACPR"
    Range("N2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N" & LR)
    Range("N2:N" & LR).Select
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

Just read what the error is telling you - you have a duplicate declaration. Sure enough, in your code you have `Dim LR As Long` twice.

Comment: Thanks...  I reset the declaration to something like Dim LR1, and it ran.  I was hoping there was an easier way to re-declare, so that I could spend a bit less time cleaning the macro up.